# Used Arc.centroid to plot circles - but text do no go along with it why?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've used arc.Centroid to try to plot my circles on the arcs with labels. However, the labels do not stay with it?

force.on("tick", function() {

```
 text.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 6; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 4; });           

   node.attr("transform", function(d,i) {

   return "translate(" + arc[i].centroid(d) + ")"; })
```

});

I have attempted to put centroid & arc[i] instead of the x & y. How can I put my circles with text? http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/20/

Also say if I were to have more json data, would I be able to restrict the plots only going into each section e.g. each section being a category?

Any help would be great. I think the solution may be similar to this - http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/GQDUS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the force layout is not the right choice for your application. Try to group your symbol and text in a `g` element and place them at the calculated coordinates. See updated fiddle without force layout: http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/26/

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
      return "translate(" + arc[i].centroid() + ")"; 
    });

node.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) { return d.type; }))
    // change (0,0) for exact symbol placement
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .style("fill", "blue" );

node.append("text") 
      .text(function(d) { return d.Name; })
      // shift text in nice position
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 5);
```

Comment: Eventually I'm going to put more json data into it & therefore, it will begin to overlap over each node/text etc. Is there another way to prevent that happening.

Comment: Also, can't the text return the position of the symbol + 5 etc? Rather than hard coding it? But, thanks again!